# Associate an a progressive id to an html element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with several `<div>` and `<p>` and I would assign each of them a numerical identifier progressive. I would like this to be done in JavaScript.

I did it in this way but I don't know whether it is right. There are better ways to do it? Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script>
        var id = -1;
        function createId() {
            return id++;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id = "createId();">
            createId();
            <h1 id = "createId();">CHAPTER I</h1>
            <h2 id = "createId();">Down the Rabbit-Hole</h2>
            <div id = "createId();"></div>
            <p id = "createId();"><strong>Alice</strong> was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it,<i> 'and what is the use of a book,'</i> thought Alice<i> 'without pictures or conversations?’.</i></p>

            <p id = "createId();">So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a <strong>White Rabbit</strong> with pink eyes ran close by her.
            There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, <i>'Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!'</i> (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural). But when the <strong>Rabbit</strong> actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, <strong>Alice</strong> started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You realise this attribute (`id`) is not interpreted, so literally *every* element has the id `createId();`

Comment: This ---> `id = "createId();"` is NOt evaluated.

Comment: Are you forced to use JS ? This should be done server side IMHO.
Dont mix js and html. Make only one create_id function, give each element the same class, and the function should loop on them and add ID. Don't forget to check if an ID already exists, as they are unique.

Comment: Also, this seems like an XY Problem - why would you *want* every element to have sequential id's?

Comment: @Jamiec My html page contains mostly text and I would like each section had its own id so that it is identifiable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than having to output the function each time, you could just create a `window.onload` function.

```
window.document.onload = function(e) { 
  var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
  var i = -1;
  for(var x = 0; x <= all.length; x++) {
    // test the tag - what types need to be assigned an id?
    if (elem.tagName != "DIV" && elem.tagName != "P") continue;
    i++;
    all[x].setAttribute("id", i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Embedding Javascript is HTML generally a bad idea, try to separate them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="/js/your-script-file.js">/script>
</head>

<body>
   <div>
     <h1>CHAPTER I</h1>
     <h2>Down the Rabbit-Hole</h2>
     <div></div>
     <p><strong>Alice</strong> was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it,<i> 'and what is the use of a book,'</i> thought Alice<i> 'without pictures or conversations?’.</i></p>
     <p>So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a <strong>White Rabbit</strong> with pink eyes ran close by her.
            There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, <i>'Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!'</i> (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural). But when the <strong>Rabbit</strong> actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, <strong>Alice</strong> started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Then add an id to each node.

```
function addIds() {

    var nodes = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var id = 1; 

    for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) {
        nodes[i].id = 'unique' + id++
    }

}

addIds();
```

Why prefixing wit unique?

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: This should be running once the page loads - you could have a race condition here.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script>
        var id = -1;
        function createId() {
            return id++;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var text=
'    <div id = "createId();">\n'+
'            createId();\n'+
'            <h1 id = "createId();">CHAPTER I</h1>\n'+
'            <h2 id = "createId();">Down the Rabbit-Hole</h2>\n'+
'            <div id = "createId();"></div>\n'+
'            <p id = "createId();"><strong>Alice</strong> was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or conversations in it,<i> \'and what is the use of a book,\'</i> thought Alice<i> \'without pictures or conversations?’.</i></p>\n'+
'\n'+
'            <p id = "createId();">So she was considering in her own mind (as well as she could, for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid), whether the pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a <strong>White Rabbit</strong> with pink eyes ran close by her.\n'+
'            There was nothing so very remarkable in that; nor did Alice think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, <i>\'Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!\'</i> (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural). But when the <strong>Rabbit</strong> actually took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket, and looked at it, and then hurried on, <strong>Alice</strong> started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large rabbit-hole under the hedge.</p>\n'+
'    </div>';
document.write(text.replace(/createId\(\);/g, createId));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I think using PHP is better if can.